# Python 3.2.3 programming...Almost had it working

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = float(input("What is/was the cost of the meal?"))
y = float(input("What is/was the sales tax?"))
z = float(input("What percentage tip would you like to leave?"))

print ("Original Food Charge: ${}"
.format(x*1)))
print ("Sales Tax: ${}"
.format((y/100)*x)))
print ("Tip: ${}"
.format(x*(z/100)))
print ("Total Charge For Food: ${}"
.format(x+((y/100)*x)+((z/100)*x)))

error output:
```

line 10, in  Syntax Error: .format(x*1))):, line 1017

I have been told that this works in 2.6 but it does not work STILL in 3.2.3

I'm attempting to write a program that calculates the total amount of a meal purchased at a restaurant.  The program should ask the user to enter the charge for the food and the percentage of the sales tax.  The program should then ask the user what percentage of tip they would like to leave (Example: 18%).  Finally the program should display the total charge for the food, the sales tax on the total charge for the food (total food charge * sales tax rate), the tip for the meal (total food charge * tip percentage), and finally the total cost of the meal (food charge + sales tax + tip).

Comment: It is hard to keep track of what has been asked for and what's a good answer if the question changes iteratively with each attempt to answer it. Here it happened 4 times already and most answers seem to no longer match the question, although they did at the time they were posted. Try to stick to one question. Avoid discussions. If at all, discuss in comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may want to use *strings* in those input statements:

```
x = float(input("What is/was the cost of the meal?"))
```

In addition, it *may* be a good idea to use `{0}` in your format strings (rather than `{}`), at least if you want to keep compatible with pre-2.7 Python (although in that case, I'd probably be using `raw_input` as well). Even *after* 2.7, I still prefer the positional specifiers since it makes it clearer for me.

This code works fine for me:

```
x = float(input("What is/was the cost of the meal?"))
y = float(input("What is/was the sales tax?"))
z = float(input("What percentage tip would you like to leave?"))

print ("Original Food Charge: ${0}".format(x))
print ("Sales Tax: ${0}".format(y*x))
print ("Tip: ${0}".format(x*z))
print ("Total Charge For Food: ${0}".format(x+(y*x)+(z*x)))
```

such as with:

```
What is/was the cost of the meal?50
What is/was the sales tax?.05
What percentage tip would you like to leave?.1
Original Food Charge: $50.0
Sales Tax: $2.5
Tip: $5.0
Total Charge For Food: $57.5
```

Though you may want to make it clear that the "percentages" should be in fractional format, lest entering 20 as your tip will make the waiter/waitress *very* happy.

Or, you can divide `y` and `z` by 100 to turn them from percentages to fractions.

Comment: lol yeah I changed to:                                          print ("Original Food Charge: ${0}"
   .format(x))
print ("Sales Tax: ${0}"
   .format((.01*y)*x))
print ("Tip: ${0}"
   .format(x*(z*.01))
print ("Total Charge For Food: ${0}"
   .format(x+((y*.01)*x)+((.01*z)*x)))

Comment: still doesn't work though>>>error output:line 15, in <module>
Syntax Error: print ("Total Charge For Food: ${0}": line 155

Comment: @user1693293, then you have something else wrong with your code. The code provided works fine under 2.6.x. I suggest you start with that code first, or post your changed code for analysis.

Comment: okay thank you very much. btw you pointing out x/100 vs (x*.01) made me laugh. I think backwards when I'm under stress. thx again

Answer (score 1):

```
input(What is/was the cost of the meal?)
```

Is bad. `input()` wants a *string* as an argument.

```
input('What is/was the cost of the meal?')
```

This is going to happen on all three of those lines. python should tell you that these symbols are not defined.

Comment: thank you I fixed these errors !

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around your strings, e.g., `x = float(input("What is/was the cost of the meal?"))`
 You also need to read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to learn the basics of Python.