# why doesn't this work on python 3.2.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python 3.2.3 programming…Almost had it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558717/python-3-2-3-programming-almost-had-it-working)

```
x = float(input("What is/was the cost of the meal?"))
y = float(input("What is/was the sales tax?"))
z = float(input("What percentage tip would you like to leave?"))

print ("Original Food Charge: ${}"
.format(x)))
print ("Sales Tax: ${}"
.format((y/100)*x)))
print ("Tip: ${}"
.format(x*(z/100)))
print ("Total Charge For Food: ${}"
.format(x+((y/100)*x)+((z/100)*x)))
```

output error:

line 10, in 
Syntax Error: .format(x))):line 1015

Someone report that this worked in their earlier version of python (v2.6 I think). I'm using the later 3.2.3 and racking my darn brain as to why this is not working to this version. It makes sense to me someone please ENLIGHTEN me.

Comment: edit your original question,, asking same problem in different question won't help...

Comment: I have edited my original question which is fully updated. It is being seemingly ignored, one of the programmers that was answering my questions suggested I repost my code to have it analyzed.

Comment: @user1693293 Is it working as expected now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a parentheses missing after `.format(x*(z/100))` that belongs to the preceding `print`.

It should be:

```
print ("Tip: ${}".format(x*(z/100)))
```

**UPDATE:** Not sure if you got it working or not yet, here is the complete code after fixing your unbalanced parentheses...

```
x = float(input("What is/was the cost of the meal?"))
y = float(input("What is/was the sales tax?"))
z = float(input("What percentage tip would you like to leave?"))

print ("Original Food Charge: ${}"
.format(x))
print ("Sales Tax: ${}"
.format((y/100)*x))
print ("Tip: ${}"
.format(x*(z/100)))
print ("Total Charge For Food: ${}"
.format(x+((y/100)*x)+((z/100)*x)))
```

Comment: thx fixed not working though :/ line 10, in <module>
Syntax Error:    .format(x*1))):, line 1017

Comment: `.format(x*1)))`? Where are you getting this line, you did not provide this in your question? What is line 1017?

Comment: I have no idea! should I replace with .format(x))) which doesn't work either?

Comment: I think you have modified your code incorrectly, perhaps update your question with your current code and error?

Answer (score 4):

You missed an end bracket after the third print: `.format(x*(z/100)))`

Here is what appears to be a working version after I fixed the brackets:

```
x = float(input("What is/was the cost of the meal?"))
y = float(input("What is/was the sales tax?"))
z = float(input("What percentage tip would you like to leave?"))

print("Original Food Charge: ${}".format(x))
print("Sales Tax: ${}".format((y/100)*x))
print("Tip: ${}".format(x*(z/100)))
print("Total Charge For Food: ${}".format(x+((y/100)*x)+((z/100)*x)))
```

Also there is no need for newlines if the line width is less than 79.

Comment: I have fixed what your have recommended and now still getting: line 10, in <module>
Syntax Error:.format(x))): line 1015...........suggestions?

Comment: @user1693293 I believe I fixed the brackets so I posted that code now

Comment: oh wow man how did you do this...! so much simpler and less of it and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a close paren on the preceding line:

```
.format(x*(z/100))
```

Comment: ok i made change and still doesn't run any suggestions that are obvious to you?